# how to make a function when clicked on a image

Tags: image, function, dictionary

I made an image into a map with images-map.com

I made some clickable areas, but i cant figure out how to make a function when i click on one of the areas. When I click on the images it will direct me to a website.

```
<img id="Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2014-02-12-182158" src=images/map2.png border="0" width="491" height="360" usemap="#image-maps-2014-02-12-182158" alt="" />

<map name="image-maps-2014-02-12-182158" id="ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2014-02-12-182158">

<area shape="rect" coords="489,358,491,360" alt="Image Map" title="Image Map" href="http://www.image-maps.com/index.php?aff=mapped_users_0" />

<area id="cen" shape="poly" coords="242,117,227,117,212,143,232,175,244,173,252,169,264,166,272,161,278,155" alt="Centrum" title="Centrum" target="_self" href="http://www.image-maps.com/"     />
</map>
```

I want to make a function that loads an ID of a highchart that I made when I click on that part of the image.

I tried to replace the href="http://www.image-maps.com/" with an id but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean JavaScript function? If yes, use JavaScript Framework, for example jQuery. If you use jQuery, here is simple event that will be bind to any img HTML tag.

```
$("img").click(function(){
alert("The image clicked");
}};
```